# Llave foranea en Entity Framework devuelve ruta del modelo

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Hola estoy siguiendo la documentacion oficial de microsoft para poder relacionar dos tablas y al hacer la consulta en vez de devolverme el dato que necesito de otra tabla me devuelve la ruta del modelo en el proyecto de esa tabla

Este es el modelbuilder de la relacion:

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {

            modelBuilder.Entity<venta>()
                .HasOne(p => p.usuario)
                .WithMany(a => a.ventas);
}
```

la clase de la tabla usuario:

```
  public class usuario
    {
        public int usuarioId { get; set; }
        public string nombre { get; set; }
        public string apellidos { get; set; }
        public string correo { get; set; }
        public string clave { get; set; }
        public bool? estado { get; set; }
        public List<venta> ventas { get; set; }
}
```

la clase de la tabla venta:

```
   public class venta
    {
        public int ventaId { get; set; }
        public DateTime fecha { get; set; }
       // public int usuarioId { get; set; }
       //public int usuarioId { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
       public usuario usuario { get; set; }
    }
```

Aqui tengo el NotMapped ya que si no lo pongo cuando hago la migracion me crea dos columnas usuarioId y usuarioId1

Aca es donde esta el problema tengo un boton para llenar un datagrid view

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (var context = new AppDbContext()) {
             dataGridView1.DataSource = context.venta.Select(p=>p).Include(b =>b.usuario).ToList();

                //context.venta.Include(u => u.usuario.nombre).ToList();

            }
        }
```

con este codigo me llena el usuarioId y fecha en el data, pero al acceder al B.usuario me carga kandor.modelos.usuario y yo quiero que se cargue el nombre del usuario en vez de la id
¿Que es lo que estoy haciendo mal?

Estoy usando Entity Framework Core 3.1.4

Answer (score 0):

Te carga todo el modelo `Usuario` entero.

Si quieres sólo el nombre, puedes hacer el `Select`.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   using (var context = new AppDbContext()) {
      var users = context.venta.Include(b => b.usuario);
      dataGridView1.DataSource = users.Select(user => user.nombre).ToList();
   }
}
```

Espero que sirva.